# How can I convert Raw image(NEF) to video or jpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg on ubuntu, when I was trying resolution dropped.
ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 1 -i DSC_0006.NEF  -vcodec libx264 -f rawvideo -s 6000x4000  b.mp4

Comment: `-f rawvideo` will yield a raw stream, not a MP4.

Comment: I changed code :ffmpeg -f image2 -r 1 -i DSC_0006.NEF e.mp4, ı want 6000x4000 but it comes 160x120

Comment: ffmpeg can't read DSLR RAW files. You have to use dcraw to get PNM and feed that to ffmpeg.

Comment: I tried this code:dcraw -a -c -H 0 -6 -W -q 3 DSC_0006.NEF | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -vcodec ppm -r 1 -i pipe:0 -vcodec prores_ks -profile:v 3 -vendor ap10 -pix_fmt yuv444p10 -y -r 1 output.mov , video property says 6000x4000 but when ı opened the video resolution drops.